# C# Data Deserialization from JSON string - Variable routing

Tags: c#, .net, json.net, deserialization, json-deserialization

I am consuming a simple REST API. The way I usually do this from my .Net environment is to use a HttpClient and just use Newstonsoft JSON.NET to deserialize the JSON response back into a class I have created.

I usually just create my variables with the same name as the JSON variable so it can map and be deserialized correctly.

However the variables in the current API I am consuming just do not make that much sense so I am wondering if it is at possible to have something like the below so that I can name my class variables correctly but still have the deserialization map back.

```
[Serializable(Name="param1")]
public string CompanyName { get; set; }
```

Answer (score 2):

Use:

```
[JsonProperty("param1")]
public string CompanyName {get; set;}
```

Or:

```
[JsonProperty(PropertyName="param1")]
public string CompanyName {get; set;}
```